# Fontspec crash with xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, compilation-error

I'm having a crash with XeLaTeX on any file that uses the `fontspec` package. I get this as the error:

```
! LaTeX error: "kernel/invalid-variant"
! 
! Variant form 'e' invalid for base form '\tl_if_empty_p:n'.
```

This is odd, because I just came back to doing some TeX work after a month or two, and as far as I know, nothing has changed at all since the last time it worked. I just updated MiKTeX and that hasn't solved the problem.

Minimal failing example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Junicode}

\begin{document}

test

\end{document}
```

If I remove the `\usepackage` and `\setmainfont` commands, it works fine.

I know very little about the internals of TeX programs, so I am completely at a loss here. What is going on?

Comment: Update as user *and* as admin.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried to update it from the miktex-update.exe files, and it gave a bunch of errors and now seems to have halfway uninstalled itself - those exe files no longer exist, and several other files such as TeXworks and the uninstaller copystart_admin.exe. I don't even know how to finish uninstalling it to reinstall it, as the file that the Windows uninstaller calls is now gone.

Comment: Search for the MiKTeX console.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, there's the uninstall option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Something is horribly broken in my system - reinstalling from scratch seems to finish, then throws an error that just says this: "Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:

  Option --admin only makes sense for a shared MiKTeX setup.

Error: The executed process did not succeed." Log file says "  info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1" "

Comment: Add an issue at the miktex issue tracker (but I think there is already one with this error) or use texlive instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer See also https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/355

Comment: @Sjiveru The newest `fontspec` depends on the newest `l3kernel` (the LaTeX3 kernel). Could you check if your `l3kernel` is up-to-date?

Comment: @RuixiZhang I know, that (and this question) is the typical problem of a only partly updated miktex installation - every second day there is someone who didn't run updates in both modes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Just ran into a similar problem with the `setmainfont` command not being recognized after updating as "admin" using the MikTeX console. Your advice to update as  "user" as well solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Switching to TeXLive seems to have solved my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same problem. After reading comments above, tried updating the MikTeX both in user and admin modes but failed.

Later on, I search for `l3kernel` (inside MikTeX Console >> Packages) and found that it wasn't installed at all. After installing `l3kernel` and its packing via MikTeX Console >> Packages, everything is working as earlier!